# Adding/Appending an element to a python list

Tags: python, list, append

I read on [this site](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_list_manipulation.php) that while appending elements to a list, say L, although the approaches:

```
L + [42]
```

and

```
L.append(42)
```

give the same result, the first approach is not same as the second and also that the first approach should never be used. Why is it so?

Comment: *"We can see that the "+" operator is about 1268 slower than the append method"* - from the page you linked. It also offers a nice explanation of the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`L + [42]` generates a new list, `L.append(42)` modifies the list L.

In practice, modifying is often needed, so while it is possible to do something like `L = L + [42]` for a new list to be generated and placed to the variable L (it's like making a copy of a picture sitting in a frame, modifying the copy and putting it into the same frame, destroying the original picture), `L.append(42)` is far more efficient (like changing the picture directly).

Answer (score -1):

You also can extend a list using the **extend** command:

```
a = [1 ,2, 3]
b = [4, 5]
a.extend(b)
```

**a** will be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and **b** stays the same.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Some people downvote answers which they think do not answer the question.